# Is there <Navigate> as react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

In parent

```
import LoginPage from "pages/admin";

export function Home() {
  return <LoginPage />;
}
```

In child

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";


export default function LoginPage() {
  const router = useRouter();
  return (router.replace("/users");)
```

I got JSX error.

Because child is not used JSX.

But in react-router-dom, There is `<Navigate>`.

So in that case, it can fix.

Is there `<Navigate>` as react-router-dom in Next.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `router.push` for redirections:

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

// Here you would fetch and return the user
const useUser = () => ({ user: null, loading: false })

export default function Page() {
  const { user, loading } = useUser()
  const router = useRouter()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!(user || loading)) {
      router.push('/login')
    }
  }, [user, loading])

  return <p>Redirecting...</p>
}
```

Next documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router

## Custom JSX component

If you need a component to do this:

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

function Redirect({ to }) {
  const router = useRouter()

  useEffect(() => {
    router.push(to)
  }, [])

  return null
}
```

Then just use it as a react-router `<Redirect to="" />`

Comment: Nothing JSX options?

Comment: I'll edit my answer with a JSX component doing the same